# use of abstract class containing non-abstract methods only

Tags: java, abstract-class

There is an abstract class containing non-abstract methods only. Now I create another class which extends abstract class. For ex :

```
    abstract class Parent{
        void No(){
            System.out.println("abcd");
        }
    }

class Child extends Parent {
}
```

Instead of abstract class, I could have create another class. What is use of making this above class as an Abstract ?

Comment: your question is not phrased clearly , so it's hard to understand what you're asking exactly. is your question  "what concrete examples we have for abstract classes"? any way , add a language tag such as Java or such

Comment: if you have an abstract class without abstract methods, a good example i can think of is that you intend to have clients to use a set of factory methods to instantiate the class instead of calling the constructor, such that you can introduce extra behavior out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to know is if in this case it make any difference not to make abstract:

**No it doesn't**: as long as you do not have abstract methods, you can use abstract or non-abstract classes (even if `abstract` makes no sense in this case). But if you've one abstract method, you class needs to be marked as abstract.

Comment: it makes a lot of differences... an abstract class cannot be instantiated in the first place.

Comment: Ok, yes; you're right you need to write `Class newClass = new Class(){};` instead of `Class newClass = new Class();`. I'd say it's a minor diff but ok it's a difference.

Answer (score 0):

an abstract class without any abstract methods sometimes is a design decision. for example, a regular expression can be implemented like this:

```
public abstract class Regex {
    private Regex(String pattern) { /* do something */ }

    private static class ConcreteRegex {
        private ConcreteRegex(String pattern) {
            super(pattern);
        }
    }

    private static final int MAX_CACHE_SIZE = 100;
    private static Object cacheLock = new Object();
    private static Queue<String> patternq = new LinkedList<>();
    private static Map<String, Regex> cache = new HashMap<>();

    private static Regex checkCache(String pattern) {
        synchronized(cacheLock) {
            return cache.get(pattern);
        }
    }

    private static void insertCache(String pattern, Regex regex) {
        synchronized(cacheLock) {
            patternq.offer(pattern);
            cache.put(pattern, regex);
            while(patternq.size() >= MAX_CACHE_SIZE) {
                String key = patternq.poll();
                cache.remove(key);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Regex compile(String pattern) {
        Regex result = checkCache(pattern);
        if (result == null) {
            Regex compiled = new ConcreteRegex(pattern);
            insertCache(pattern, compiled);
            return compiled;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static Matcher match(String pattern, String str) {
        Regex result = compile(pattern);
        return result.matches(str);
    }

    // define find, findall, and so on like this
}
```

so what's the point to do all these work? well, sometimes it would be quite handy to have these methods to shorten the program, while it may have a chance to increase the performance of the program. by doing this, we need to prevent user to call the constructor directly. but why not have these caching management inside of the constructor?

well, this is not recommended(it will compile though), since you are leaking the instance out in the middle of instantiation, such that there is a chance to reference the partially instantiated object, which may generally be considered as a dangerous behavior.

of course, there are other cases where you decide to have such "weird" abstract classes, which are too many to enumerate.

Comment: I don't understand your example. The constructor of `Regex` is private, so outside code couldn't instantiate it even if it weren't abstract.

Comment: @ruakh that's the purpose. `Regex` can only be instantiated through provided methods. users should use `compile` to get the `Regex` instance or `match`, `find` these kind of static utils to get the results directly.

Comment: What I'm saying is, that would be the case *whether or not* `Regex` is abstract.

Comment: @ruakh this can even prevent user cheating by using reflection, right?

Comment: Nothing prevents a fellow programmer from cheating by copying your source-code and modifying the One Magic Property that you're concerned about. Reflection is a red herring. Your teammates are not your enemy.

Comment: @ruakh i take that as a protection. sometimes a library has a specific feature or assumption that needs to be protected and the reason behind is hard to explain, while teammates may not or may not need to be aware of this. i think it's fine, it's not damaging anything.

Comment: Re: "i think it's fine, it's not damaging anything": Then you're mistaken. \*shrug\*

Answer (score 0):

It's true that if an abstract class has no abstract methods, then there's nothing that *forcibly* prevents would-be clients from creating a trivial child class and instantiating it; but keep in mind that we write code to be read and understood, not just by the compiler, but by other programmers (including our future selves). We cannot *forcibly* prevent those programmers from messing up; but we can write code that helps them do the right thing.

So the question is — what is a situation where a class has no abstract methods, but where it nonetheless doesn't make sense to instantiate it directly?

There are a few possibilities that come to mind, but I'll just mention one.

Consider an interface like `java.util.List`, where many of the methods are convenience methods that can be defined in terms of others. In particular, the methods that use iterators can be defined in terms of the methods that use indices, and vice versa.

One could easily imagine an abstract `List` implementation that defines *all* of these methods, but in terms of each other. You could then easily implement `List` by subclassing this implementation and overriding either an iterator-y method or an index-y method.

(As it happens, this is not the approach the JDK takes. The JDK instead offers two abstract implementations, `java.util.AbstractList` and `java.util.AbstractSequentialList`, each of which has some abstract methods for the subclass to fill in. I think the JDK's approach is superior, because it makes it clearer what you are supposed to do, and generates a compile-error where the combined-abstract-class approach generates a `StackOverflowError` at runtime. But I would not fault the developer who, with a surfeit of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), took the combined-abstract-class approach.)

Answer (score 0):

One advantage I see is that you **prevent people instantiate it.**

For example you want to make a system of vehicle. In the parent abstract class, there is only one method run(){}, well, not abstract. You want to instantiate it as VW, TOYOTA OR Ford, but not a non-specified brand vehicle. You inherent vehicle class as non abstract class VW, Toyota or Ford. but you couldn't start with vehicle, cuz it's more like a "type", not something you want to build.